# When the mouse moves on the grid, so does the corresponding point on the map

Tags: javascript, grids-graticules, mouse-position, plot

I am trying to create a specific functionality in mapping application.

The application currently lets users draw a profile line on a map and click run. The map then takes a DEM file and creates a grid below the image that shows "the lay of the land;" in other words it shows a 2 dimensional display of the elevation on an x/y axis that traces the rise and fall along the profile line that the user initially created.

What I want to do is have a ball appear on the profile line in the map that traces the mouse movements when the user's mouse cursor is on the grid (I already have crosshair, highlight ball, and elevation tooltip that uses the Flot plothover functionality).

Does anyone know of an application that already has this functionality or know of a way to achieve this; even in simplistic terms?

I am currently able to pull out the coordinates that trace the initial profile line on the map (decimal degrees), but I am not sure how to relate them to the grid coordinates (not real coordinates, basically just elevation values and values relating to points on the x-axis).

Comment: What mapping library are you using for your application, Leaflet, Mapbox, OpenLayers..?

Comment: OpenLayers is what is currently being used. I am using the JQuery Flot plugin for the grid.